# Find next highest and next lowest number in list c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of numbers and if the number that I am looking for is not in the list I want to be able to find the next value that is in the list above and below the number that I have asked for.

```
double index = 5;
List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, };
//do code to find next highest/lowest
double higher = 7;
double lower = 3;
```

for example, because 5 is not exactly in the list itself I want it to return the next item that is closest to 5 both above and below. so for this case, 3 and 7.

Comment: @maceturra, he wants to find higher and lower when the input is not in the list, so finding the index of the input is not possible.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem yourself? This looks like homework to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Original version

You can use List's `Sort()` method, then use LINQ `FirstOrDefault()` and `LastOrDefault()`

```
List<double> numbers = new List<double>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9
};

double input = 5;
    
numbers.Sort();

double nextHighest = numbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x > input);
double nextLowest = numbers.LastOrDefault(x => x < input);
```

### <s>Better version edit</s> This wont actually work for both cases

Originally I suggested this as a more efficient solution, but this will not work for the number *before* a given input.  It only works for finding a number *after* the given input.

<s>You can be more efficient since you are using `List<T>`, there is a `Find()` method that accepts a predicate:</s>

```
List<double> numbers = new List<double>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9
};

double input = 5;
    
numbers.Sort();

double nextHighest = numbers.Find(x => x > input);
```

This will [exit the loop immediately](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,420) upon finding a match (whereas `LastOrDefault()` has to [iterate the entire collection](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/b31308b03e8bd5bf779fb80fda71f31eb959fe0b/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1136))

Fiddle for both [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xaykmQ)

Comment: I have to admit that this solution is elegant, but it's the most efficient?

Comment: @CosminIoniță It is not the most efficient, but I think it will be efficient enough for the problem at hand.  I will edit to add a disclaimer.

Comment: What would you consider to be a very large list in this case?

Comment: @maccettura: Good job! Looks very elegant now, but regarding the complexity (just for the sake of speaking), isn't it ```O(n * log(n))```? Can't this problem be solved in ```O(n)``` time?

Comment: Whats going on here ? The better version is not working correct. No one saw it or i don't understand ? Take a look at the fiddle - one method returns 7,3  and the other 7,1

Comment: @RumenYankov You're right, I don't know how I never noticed this.  The `Find()` method will work on items that are the first _above_ the given input, but not the first item _below_.

Answer (score 0):

LinQ-Solution:

```
double index = 5;
List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, };

double higher=list.OrderBy(q=>q).First(q=>q>index); // 7
double lower=list.OrderByDescending(q=>q).First(q=>q<index); // 3
```

Explanation: First you sort the list Ascending or Descending. After that all you have to do is to find the greater or smaller number;

You might want to replace `First()` by `FirstOrDefault()` if you do not want an exception if no higher/lower value exists.

Comment: Seems weird to order by twice.

Comment: On the worst case your solution takes ```O(n * log(n))``` time

Comment: @maccettura I thought of this as two completely different requirements

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be sort the list and then iterate over it to find the spot where list[i] < index < list[i+1]. This would take `O(n * log(n))` time.

A better solution is simply iterate over the list and use 2 variables that you will update accordingly (let's say `max` and `min`).

`max` will store the maximum value that is below the index.

`min` will store the minimum value that is above the index.

That last solution takes `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want all the occurency

```
double index = 5;
List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, };
for(int i =1 ; i <= 9-5 ; i++)
{
    List<double> NextHigh = list.Where(x=> x-i == index).ToList();
    if(! (NextHigh.Count == 0))
    {
        NextHigh.Dump();
        break;
    }
}

for(int i =1 ; i <= 5-1 ; i++)
{
    List<double> NextLow = list.Where(x=> x+i == index).ToList();
    if( !(NextLow.Count== 0))
    {
        NextLow.Dump();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer given is not very good if you are going to be using a large list of values, because it needs to index the list twice.

If you make your own loop like this:

```
double higher = Double::MaxValue;
double lower = Double::MinValue;

double index = 5; // the value you want to get.
List<double> list = {1,2,3,7,8,9}; // the list you're searching.

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
{
    if(list[i] > index && list[i] < higher)
        higher = list[i]; // sets the higher value.
    else if(list[i] < index && list[i] > lower)
        lower = list[i]; // sets the lower value.
}
```

After execution, this would give you 3 and 7, the correct values.

I should note that this takes O(n) time, because it only loops once. This will be faster than anything posted at the time of this edit (plus it's pretty easy to see what its doing).

Comment: That's true. I have to work on that still in my programming, I fall back on that too much.

Answer (score -1):

You can archieve that by this way. These codes below was tested from my side.

```
    double index = 5;
    double higher = 0 ;
    double lower = 0;

    List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, };
    list.Sort();//Sort list from low to high numbers

    if(!list.Contains(index))
    {
      foreach (var item in list)
      {
         if(item < index)
         {
            lower = item;                      
         }
         if (item > index)
         {
             higher = item;  
             break;  
         }
       }
     }
Console.WriteLine(index);//5
Console.WriteLine(lower);//3
Console.WriteLine(higher);//7
```

Comment: Your solution works ONLY if the list is sorted. The original post does not say that. You have to assume that your list is not sorted.

Comment: @Cosmin ,Yes,You're right so  I updated my code, now it can cover the case the list is not sorted.